# The proof of 'Infinite set is disjoint union of countable set' in Anthony Knapp's basic algebra

Tags: set-theory

I am reading Prof. Anthony Knapp's basic algebra recently. When I tried to understand a proof in the appendix of this book, I found that there might be some thing wrong in the proof.

[image]

The definition of the partial order is not well-defined. Under the definition provided by him, we cannot even prove that for any set $A$, we have $A \leq A$ using the partial order $\leq $, since for any set $A$, it can have many different partitions. Can anyone explain to me how to change this proof to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knapp is being a little loose with notation, and maybe with terminology too.  When he defines $S$ as the set of all "disjoint unions" of countably infinite subsets of $E$ (which suggests that the elements of $S$ are subsets of $E$), what he really means is the set of all *families of pairwise disjoint countably infinite subsets of $E$*.  That is, the elements of $S$ are not sets, but tuples $(A_\alpha)$ where the $A_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint countably infinite subsets of $E$.  We can think of such a family as an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(E))$, the power set of the power set of $E$, and the partial order he uses is just the containment partial order that every power set has.